# I need help on the math for detecting the "side" of collision on a rotating sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I am making a 2D space shmup that handles combat in a naval way.  So you shoot out the broadsides of the ship, your shields and hull are divided into 4 sections: Forward, Starboard, Port, and Rear.  I am not the greatest with math, but I managed to find a script that detects the side of my polygon collider that was hit by say a collision or projectile.  That all works great.

The problem is my sprite rotates to steer in 2D space.  So when I collide with something say for example with the nose of my ship, if my ship's nose is up then the collision is detected properly.  But if the ship is rotated and the nose is now on the left and I collide with something on the nose, the script will detect the nose collision as a port side collision instead.  Could somebody help me with correcting the math to account for my ship's rotation?

**Collision2DExtension.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace PixelsoftGames
{
    public static class Collision2DExtensions
    {
        public static Collision2DSideType GetContactSide(Vector2 max, Vector2 center, Vector2 contact)
        {
            Collision2DSideType side = Collision2DSideType.None;
            float diagonalAngle = Mathf.Atan2(max.y - center.y, max.x - center.x) * 180 / Mathf.PI;
            float contactAngle = Mathf.Atan2(contact.y - center.y, contact.x - center.x) * 180 / Mathf.PI;

            if (contactAngle < 0)
            {
                contactAngle = 360 + contactAngle;
            }

            if (diagonalAngle < 0)
            {
                diagonalAngle = 360 + diagonalAngle;
            }

            if (
                ((contactAngle >= 360 - diagonalAngle) && (contactAngle <= 360)) ||
                ((contactAngle <= diagonalAngle) && (contactAngle >= 0))
            )
            {
                side = Collision2DSideType.Starboard;
            }
            else if (
                ((contactAngle >= 180 - diagonalAngle) && (contactAngle <= 180)) ||
                ((contactAngle >= 180) && (contactAngle <= 180 + diagonalAngle))
            )
            {
                side = Collision2DSideType.Port;
            }
            else if (
                ((contactAngle >= diagonalAngle) && (contactAngle <= 90)) ||
                ((contactAngle >= 90) && (contactAngle <= 180 - diagonalAngle))
            )
            {
                side = Collision2DSideType.Forward;
            }
            else if (
                ((contactAngle >= 180 + diagonalAngle) && (contactAngle <= 270)) ||
                ((contactAngle >= 270) && (contactAngle <= 360 - diagonalAngle))
            )
            {
                side = Collision2DSideType.Rear;
            }

            return side.Opposite();
        }

        static bool ranOnce = false;
        public static Collision2DSideType GetContactSide(this Collision2D collision)
        {
            Vector2 max = collision.collider.bounds.max;
            Vector2 center = collision.collider.bounds.center;
            Vector2 contact = collision.GetContact(0).point;

            if (!ranOnce)
            {
                ranOnce = true;
                Debug.Log("Max: " + max);
                Debug.Log("Center: " + center);
                Debug.Log("Contact: " + contact);
            }

            return GetContactSide(max, center, contact);
        }
    }
}
```

**Collision2DSideTypeExtensions.cs**

```
namespace PixelsoftGames
{
    public static class Collision2DSideTypeExtensions
    {
        public static Collision2DSideType Opposite(this Collision2DSideType sideType)
        {
            Collision2DSideType opposite;

            if (sideType == Collision2DSideType.Port)
            {
                opposite = Collision2DSideType.Starboard;
            }
            else if (sideType == Collision2DSideType.Starboard)
            {
                opposite = Collision2DSideType.Port;
            }
            else if (sideType == Collision2DSideType.Forward)
            {
                opposite = Collision2DSideType.Rear;
            }
            else if (sideType == Collision2DSideType.Rear)
            {
                opposite = Collision2DSideType.Forward;
            }
            else
            {
                opposite = Collision2DSideType.None;
            }

            return opposite;
        }
    }
}
```

**Collision2DSideType**

```
public enum Collision2DSideType { None, Port, Starboard, Forward, Rear }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method GetContactSide you never get the rotation of your sprite, it is like your sprite angle is always 0

One solution for this is to add as a parameter the angle of your sprite to the method and add that angle to the the condition to determine wich side of the sprite it is

It can look like that :

```
public static class Collision2DExtensions
{
    public static Collision2DSideType GetContactSide(Vector2 max, Vector2 center, Vector2 contact, float angle)
    {
        ...
        if (
            ((contactAngle >= (360 - diagonalAngle) + angle) && (contactAngle <= 360 + angle)) ||
            ((contactAngle <= diagonalAngle + angle) && (contactAngle >= 0 + angle))
        )
```

...
`

I think you should do that for each of these conditions

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked fairly well!  The problem now is that Collision2DSideType.None is getting called alot.  I'm not so good with math haha.